# How to get UIView size in drawRect

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, uikit, ios11

I am using `self.bound` to get the UIView size in `drawRect` method. But now, with XCode 9, I get this warning:

> Main Thread Checker: UI API called on a background thread: -[UIView
>   bounds]

What is the right way to get the view size in `drawRect` method?

Comment: Try to dispatch on main thread.

Comment: I will try to figure out why it is called on a background thread, thanks for the hint...

Answer (score 7):

Like this:

```
override func drawRect(rect: CGRect)
    let bds = DispatchQueue.main.sync {
        return self.bounds
    }
    // ....
}
```

But the fact that `drawRect` is being called on a background thread in the first place is a bad sign — unless you're using CATiledLayer or some other built-in architecture that does this. You should be worrying first and foremost about *that*.

Comment: I am using CATiledLayer in this view, so it is normal that drawRect is called in the background.

Comment: Good, if you look at my comment and my answer, that's exactly what I was asking you to confirm! In that case, yes, this is the way out of the problem. It turns out we were doing this wrong all along; only now has the Main Thread checker come along and slapped us down. It has proved its worth!

Comment: Do you think that doing sync operation in the drawRect could slow down the drawing? What do you think about overriding layoutSubviews and keep the size into a class member?

Comment: I think it's a _great_ idea and was about to suggest it myself. :)

Comment: Thanks for your help!

Comment: Let me know how it goes; if that works, could you submit that as your own answer? (And you can even accept it in 48 hours.) You and I are not going to be the only people to hit this problem as Xcode 9 spreads.

Comment: Cool, but be sure to run under the Thread Sanitizer to make sure you haven't introduced a race condition.

Answer (score 5):

I finally found a solution for the problem. I am now overriding `layoutSubviews` of UIView to keep the view bounds in a class member:

```
- (void)layoutSubviews
{
    [super layoutSubviews];
    m_SelfBounds = self.bounds;
}
```

After that, I am just using `m_SelfBounds` in `drawRect` method.

Comment: This hasn't solved your thread safety bug - all you've done is create the same bug in a way that the compiler isn't smart enough to warn you about. The m_SelfBounds value can change half way through the drawRect operation.

Answer (score 0):

Use the "barrier" feature of Grand Central Dispatch to allow concurrent read operations while blocking those operations during a write:

```
class MyTileView: UIView
{
  var drawBounds = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 0, height: 0)
  let drawBarrierQueue = DispatchQueue(label: "com.example.app",
                                             qos: .userInteractive, // draw operations require the highest priority threading available
                                             attributes: .concurrent,
                                             target: nil)

  override func layoutSubviews() {
    drawBarrierQueue.sync(flags: .barrier) { // a barrier operation waits for active operations to finish before starting, and prevents other operations from starting until this one has finished
      super.layoutSubviews();

      self.drawBounds = self.bounds

      // do other stuff that should hold up drawing
    }
  }

  override func draw(_ layer: CALayer, in ctx: CGContext)
  {
    drawBarrierQueue.sync {
      // do all of your drawing

      ctx.setFillColor(red: 1.0, green: 0, blue: 0, alpha: 1.0)
      ctx.fill(drawBounds)
    }
  }
}
```